# ASP.NET Remote File Access with Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, file, share

I have an ASP.NET web application that is trying to read a remote share with the impersonated user. Specifically, I am trying to use the following code to read the directories on the remote share..

```
DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in rootDir.EnumerateDirectories())
{
    TreeNode folderNode = new TreeNode(dir.Name, dir.FullName);
    folderNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
    folderNode.ImageUrl = "~/img/Folder.png";
    nodeList.Add(folderNode);
}
```

When the webpage runs this code, I get the following error message...

> Access to the path '\remoteserver\remoteshare\' is denied.

Here is my web.config...

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

When I log onto the website, I know that impersonation is working because I can do an HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and see my username. I am running this application on a domain under IIS 7.5. I also know that this can't be a Kerberos "double-hop" issue because I can connect to a remote SQL server (from the web server) and pass the Windows Authenticated credentials through just fine and return results from a query.

I am using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on the web server to figure out which credentials are being passed over to the remote share. When I look at the capture where the ACCESS DENIED is showing, it gives me this description...

> Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating: DOMAIN\username

Where DOMAIN\username is my impersonated username from the web server.

Process Monitor is also showing that NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is the user on the web server that is making the request, which makes me think that the web server is NOT, in fact, passing over the impersonated user to read the remote file share. It's almost like there is a "double hop" issue for remote file share access specifically.

I have also configured the web server to "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)". Again, this can't be a double-hop issue if I can access a remote SQL server from the web server, or can it? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, I have spent 2 days looking at possible solutions and nothing works.